# Correct Way To Map s3 Key To Value In Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a list of s3 keys in a file, and I want to get their values into an RDD. What is the correct way to do this?

The code below is my current attempt. The call to pull the file down from `s3` works outside of the map function, but causes a null pointer exception inside of it. I believe this is because you cannot create or operate on RDDs inside of a map call, but I am not sure how to work around this. Are there ways to read the files from S3 in spark without putting them into an RDD? If I could read them directly into a string or inputStream that would be ideal, but I don't believe that `Source` supports the `s3a` format, it has to be something that's reading from the hadoop file system.

```
JavaRDD<String> keys = spark.sparkContext().textFile("/list/of/keys", 0).toJavaRDD();
SparkContext sc = spark.sparkContext();
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> file = spark.sparkContext().wholeTextFiles("s3a://bucket/key",0).toJavaRDD();

JavaRDD<String> files =
    keys.map(
        o -> {
            JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> rawfile = spark.sparkContext().wholeTextFiles("s3a://bucket/key",0)toJavaRDD();
            return rawFile.take(1).get(0)._2();
        }
    );
```

The reason that I am not using `wholeTextFiles` to read in multiple files is that I want to avoid making roundtrip requests to `s3`, as I've read that those can be quite expensive due to s3 not being a true filesystem.

Comment: Is your data a CSV type?

Comment: The data in s3? Or the key store?

Comment: I would like to know if you data in s3 is stored as CSV.

Comment: It is not. It's a large number of small files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution works indeed. One way to avoid looking up the file system for every keys is to use `keys.mapPartition` instead. Also, if you want to one line of your files per RDD element, you can use `IOUtils#readLines`:

```
JavaRDD<String> files =
keys.mapPartition(
    subkeys -> {
          FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
          List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

          for (k : subkeys) {
             lines.addAll(IOUtils.readLines(fs.open(new Path("/" + o))), Charset.defaultCharset());
          }

          return lines;
    }
);
```

Comment: Nice `mapPartition` looks like exactly what I need. I edited your answer for a small syntax issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I have gotten something working by using the Hadoop libraries instead of spark libraries to read in from S3.

This required setting some confs to get `s3a` working in `hdfs-site.xml`. Here's what my code looks like now:

```
JavaRDD<String> keys = spark.sparkContext().textFile("file:///list/of/keys", 0).toJavaRDD();

SparkContext sc = spark.sparkContext();

Configuration hConf = new Configuration();

JavaRDD<String> files =
    keys.map(
        o -> {
              return org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(FileSystem.get(new Configuration()).open(new Path("/" + o)));
        }
    );
```

I'm not sure if this is the fastest way to do it, but it is working.

I had to put this into `hdfs-site.xml` along with the `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key` properties.

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>s3a://bucket-name</value>
</property>
```